# Kafka producer Spring Cloud app won't publish anything

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

i started connected my spring cloud app with kafka and zookeeper hosted in docker-compose file, they're connected, but when i run the application and expect the Producer to publish a message, get nothing... i don't know what the error is, i followed this example: https://github.com/ihuaylupo/manning-smia/tree/master/chapter10/licensing-service/src/main/java/com/optimagrowth/license/events

Workflow is that from the github repo example, when i call and endPoint Post on a Service, for example, i wish to my kafka producer to publish a message on topic and Kafka consumer to consume that message, but everything works - Endpoint execute against DB, except kafka producing and consuming messaging, not even an error to know where i did wrong...

Docker-compose file:

```
 zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    

  kafkaserver:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=192.168.99.100 #kafka 192.168.99.100 #kafka - ip because i want to access kafka and zookeeper from outside of containers, i.e localhost
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=dresses:1:1, ratings:1:1
      - KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES=2000000000
      - KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx512M -Xmx5g
      - listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.99.100:9092
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Kafka consumer spring cloud properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inboundOrgChanges.destination=orgChangeTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inboundOrgChanges.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inboundOrgChanges.group=studentsGroup
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost #kafka
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=localhost
```

Kafka producer spring cloud properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=orgChangeTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=http://192.168.99.100:2181
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=http://192.168.99.100:9092
```

Kafka Producer...

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class) // - on my main Spring app
@Component
public class SimpleSourceBean {
    private Source source;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleSourceBean.class);

    @Autowired
    public SimpleSourceBean(Source source){
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void publishOrganizationChange(String action, String organizationId){
       logger.debug("Sending Kafka message {} for Organization Id: {}", action, organizationId);
        OrganizationChangeModel change =  new OrganizationChangeModel(
                OrganizationChangeModel.class.getTypeName(),
                action,
                organizationId,
                UserContext.getCorrelationId());

        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(change).build());
    }
}
```

---

```
@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class OrganizationChangeModel {
    private String type;
    private String action;
    private String organizationId;
    private String correlationId;

    public OrganizationChangeModel(String type, String action, String organizationId, String correlationId) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
        this.action = action;
        this.organizationId = organizationId;
        this.correlationId = correlationId;
    }
}

@Service class ServiceEx {
    @Autowired
    SimpleSourceBean simpleSourceBean;

    public Organization findById(String organizationId) {
        Optional<Organization> opt = repository.findById(organizationId);
        simpleSourceBean.publishOrganizationChange("GET", organizationId);
        return (opt.isPresent()) ? opt.get() : null;
    }   //wont do anything }
```

Edited:
Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=dresses:1:1, ratings:1:1
      - KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES=2000000000
      - KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx512M -Xmx5g
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network

  facultate:
    container_name: facultate
    build: C:\Users\marius\com.balabasciuc.springmicroservicesinaction\facultateservice
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "1002:1002"
    environment:
      SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI: "http://config:7070"
      EUREKA_HOST: server
      EUREKA_PORT: 9001
      DATABASE_HOST: database
     # SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_BROKERS: kafka:9092
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
      - server
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network
volumes:
  simple:
    driver: local
networks:
  spring-cloud-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Spring Cloud producer prop:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=orgChangeTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=zookeeper
```

Docker Logs:

```
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:47.246  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:47.247  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:47.251  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Creating binder: kafka
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:47.876  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Caching the binder: kafka
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:47.876  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Retrieving cached binder: kafka
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:48.138  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner      : Using kafka topic for outbound: orgChangeTopic
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:48.150  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values:
facultate    |  bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
facultate    |  client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
facultate    |  client.id =
facultate    |  connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
facultate    |  default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
facultate    |  metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
facultate    |  metric.reporters = []
facultate    |  metrics.num.samples = 2
facultate    |  metrics.recording.level = INFO
facultate    |  metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
facultate    |  receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
facultate    |  reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
facultate    |  reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
facultate    |  request.timeout.ms = 30000
facultate    |  retries = 2147483647
facultate    |  retry.backoff.ms = 100
facultate    |  sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
facultate    |  sasl.jaas.config = null
facultate    |  sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
facultate    |  sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
facultate    |  sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
facultate    |  sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
facultate    |  sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
facultate    |  sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
facultate    |  sasl.login.class = null
facultate    |  sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
facultate    |  sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
facultate    |  sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
facultate    |  sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
facultate    |  sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
facultate    |  security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
facultate    |  security.providers = null
facultate    |  send.buffer.bytes = 131072
facultate    |  socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
facultate    |  socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
facultate    |  ssl.cipher.suites = null
facultate    |  ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
facultate    |  ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
facultate    |  ssl.engine.factory.class = null
facultate    |  ssl.key.password = null
facultate    |  ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
facultate    |  ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
facultate    |  ssl.keystore.key = null
facultate    |  ssl.keystore.location = null
facultate    |  ssl.keystore.password = null
facultate    |  ssl.keystore.type = JKS
facultate    |  ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
facultate    |  ssl.provider = null
facultate    |  ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
facultate    |  ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
facultate    |  ssl.truststore.certificates = null
facultate    |  ssl.truststore.location = null
facultate    |  ssl.truststore.password = null
facultate    |  ssl.truststore.type = JKS
facultate    |
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:48.614  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.0.0
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:48.618  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 8cb0a5e9d3441962
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:48.619  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1643714148612
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:53.683  INFO 1 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:53.767  INFO 1 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:53.775  INFO 1 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:53.775  INFO 1 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:53.899  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values:
facultate    |  acks = 1
facultate    |  batch.size = 16384
facultate    |  bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
facultate    |  buffer.memory = 33554432
facultate    |  client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
facultate    |  client.id = producer-1
facultate    |  compression.type = none
facultate    |  connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
facultate    |  delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
facultate    |  enable.idempotence = true
facultate    |  interceptor.classes = []
facultate    |  key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
facultate    |  linger.ms = 0
facultate    |  max.block.ms = 60000
facultate    |  max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
facultate    |  max.request.size = 1048576
facultate    |  metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
facultate    |  metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
facultate    |  metric.reporters = []
facultate    |  metrics.num.samples = 2
facultate    |  metrics.recording.level = INFO
facultate    |  metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
facultate    |  partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
facultate    |  receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
facultate    |  reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
facultate    |  reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
facultate    |  request.timeout.ms = 30000
facultate    |  retries = 2147483647
facultate    |  retry.backoff.ms = 100
facultate    |  sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
facultate    |  sasl.jaas.config = null
facultate    |  sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
facultate    |  sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
facultate    |  sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
facultate    |  sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
facultate    |  sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
facultate    |  sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
facultate    |  sasl.login.class = null
facultate    |  sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
facultate    |  sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
facultate    |  sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
facultate    |  sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
facultate    |  sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
facultate    |  security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
facultate    |  security.providers = null
facultate    |  send.buffer.bytes = 131072
facultate    |  socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
facultate    |  socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
facultate    |  ssl.cipher.suites = null
facultate    |  ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
facultate    |  ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
facultate    |  ssl.engine.factory.class = null
facultate    |  ssl.key.password = null
facultate    |  ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
facultate    |  ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
facultate    |  ssl.keystore.key = null
facultate    |  ssl.keystore.location = null
facultate    |  ssl.keystore.password = null
facultate    |  ssl.keystore.type = JKS
facultate    |  ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
facultate    |  ssl.provider = null
facultate    |  ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
facultate    |  ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
facultate    |  ssl.truststore.certificates = null
facultate    |  ssl.truststore.location = null
facultate    |  ssl.truststore.password = null
facultate    |  ssl.truststore.type = JKS
facultate    |  transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
facultate    |  transactional.id = null
facultate    |  value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
facultate    |
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:54.147  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.0.0
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:54.148  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 8cb0a5e9d3441962
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:54.148  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1643714154147
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:54.293  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: RK0OLlwdRKK-oQ5dsWuHBw
facultate    | 2022-02-01 11:15:54.431  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'application-1.output' has 1 subscriber(s).
```

Kafka logs container:

```
kafka        | [2022-02-01 10:57:12,073] INFO [Partition dresses-0 broker=1001] Log loaded for partition dresses-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
zookeeper    | 2022-02-01 10:57:09,689 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@596] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100001f44830000 type:multi cxid:0x4e zxid:0x31 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a aborting remaining multi ops. Error Path:/admin/prefer
red_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election
kafka        | [2022-02-01 11:15:52,573] INFO Creating topic orgChangeTopic with configuration {} and initial partition assignment HashMap(0 -> ArrayBuffer(1001)) (kafka.zk.AdminZkClient)
kafka        | [2022-02-01 11:15:53,447] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 1001] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(orgChangeTopic-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
kafka        | [2022-02-01 11:15:53,484] INFO [Log partition=orgChangeTopic-0, dir=/kafka/kafka-logs-bde9c032b736] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
kafka        | [2022-02-01 11:15:53,488] INFO Created log for partition orgChangeTopic-0 in /kafka/kafka-logs-bde9c032b736/orgChangeTopic-0 with properties {} (kafka.log.LogManager)
kafka        | [2022-02-01 11:15:53,505] INFO [Partition orgChangeTopic-0 broker=1001] No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition orgChangeTopic-0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
```

If i post something to generate a message being produced for kafka, nothing appears in the logs... or in kafka

Comment: 1) Kafka nor Zookeeper are HTTP servives. Why have you added `http://` to the properties? 2) As I [have answered to you before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834379/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-with-microservices-and-docker-compose-error)... [You shouldn't be using IP addresses to connect to Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker) on the same host 3) You should have error logs in your client for connection issues

Comment: Also, `listeners` and `advertised.listeners` are not valid environment variables, so I suggest going back to what you had in your previous questions, where the compose file and spring properties were more correct

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer and thanks for the answer, i managed to connect producer with kafka and zookeeper docker containers, but when i do something with my spring boot app to produce a message to kafka, i get nothing, just: [ad | producer-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='byte[164]' to topic orgChangeTopic: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for orgChangeTopic-0:120000 ms has passed since batch creation

Comment: and nothing else, not the message i expected... i didn't start my consumer yet but i should see the producer message to console, i guess... i can show logs from kafka and spring cloud app if it s needed

Comment: That message means you've not sent enough data for the producer batch to get filled, so it sits in memory. In other words, you need to call `.flush()` on the producer, or whatever the equivalent is for cloud-stream

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer and thanks for your time to answering to my stupid questions... i edited this post to see what my final locks like, but not working for a way of another... I was decreased request.timeout and batch.size to not calling flush explicitly, and it worked then, after that, i think i somehow "break" the entire thing trying to add slk to the services and doesn't work anymore, last 2 days i was optimistic about getting the thing done, now...i was trying with confluentic image, any error to see if i did something wrong, not a clue... please, can take a look and give an advice?

Comment: Your configs look better now. I'm not sure I understand the problem anymore; what is "slk"? Changing a docker image shouldn't fix anything.

Comment: Hey, it was another component, problem is if i do something in my app resulting to sending a message in kafka (Making a Post Endpoint for ex) doesn't end in the expected behaviour... i wait for the message to  be published but it's not, and i don't know why or what i'm doing wrong. I know it worked when that batch size thing, but now, even if i expect to pass those 120000 ms to get an error (not enough bytes) like the previous error - nothing... don't know from where to start or what to do in this regard

Comment: hey @OneCricketeer it works... sorry for wasted your time with me and thanks a lot for your patience,  i'm just stupid sometime

Comment: Feel free to post an answer below that details what you've changed

Comment: Hei... it was basically just enabling the Debug logging for Spring cloud app, with this i can see the messages being posted from producer                                                                         
     'logging:
  level:
    com.netflix: WARN
    org.springframework.web: WARN
    com.project.springmicroservicesinaction: DEBUG'

Answer (score 0):

The annotation-based programming model (things such as `EnableBinding`, `Source`, `Sink` etc.) is deprecated in Spring Cloud Stream and going to be completely removed in the upcoming 4.0 line of the framework.

You can add a source using the functional style as below:

```
public Supplier< OrganizationChangeModel> source() {
  return () -> {
    //return OrganizationChangeModel here. 
  }
}
```

The binding name becomes `source-out-0` in this case since the supplier method is named as `source`.

However, in your case, since you want to programmatically publish using the REST endpoint, I suggest you use the `StreamBridge` API for doing that. See the StreamBridge [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources) for more details on that. The basic idea is that you use the `send` method of `StreamBridge` to publish data through an output binding.

A lot of examples in the Spring Cloud Stream [samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples) repository use this version of the dockerized Kafka. You might want to compare how it is set up there.

Comment: This alone doesn't change the fact that the configs are incorrect for the producer